# Switch and if statement to be used together

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column Gender which contains elements Male and Female. There is another column with the name Total Charges.

I want to calculate tax in new column .if the gender is male the tax rate is 20% and if it is female then the tax rate is 15%.

i am using below mentioned code but is giving wrong answers. can any one help

```
x=customer[ ,"gender"] %>% 
 if(x=="Female"){
   print (customer[ , "MonthlyCharges"]*0.50)
      } else {
      print(customer[ , "MonthlyCharges"]*0.20)
   }  "MonthlyCharges"]*0.20)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to create a new column based on the values in 'gender', either use `ifelse` or `case_when` in `mutate` to create the column and assign (`<-`) back the output to a new object identifier or the same object

```
library(dplyr)
customer <- customer  %>%
          mutate(new = case_when(gender == "Female" ~ MonthyCharges * 0.5,  
                  TRUE ~ MonthlyCharges * 0.2))
```

---

There are multiple issues in the OP's code.

1) Mixing `base R` methods with tidyverse

2) Using `print` instead of returning the values

3) if/else instead of ifelse as the number of elements are more than 1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can we use if else to solve the problem

Comment: @RatneshKumar. As I mentioned in the post, don't use `if/else` instead use `ifelse` `customer %>% mutate(new = ifelse(gender == 'Female', MonthlyCharges * 0.5, MonthlyCharges * 0.2))`